# Преобразование отрицательных float в int

Tags: c, c++

Ковыряясь в коде одной библиотеки, нашёл такие строчки:

```
// round dx down to avoid going too far
if(dxdy<0) z->dx = -(int)(FIX * -dxdy);
else z->dx = (int)(FIX * dxdy);
```

Здесь dxdy имеет тип float, FIX - это константа. Я решил проверить, в какую сторону округляется число при преобразовании в int, написал простенький тест, и выяснил, что по крайней мере у меня он округляется в сторону нуля и вместо этих строчек достаточно написать просто `z->dx=(int)(FIX * dxdy);`

Но везде ли это так? Это так по стандарту или может оказаться, что на других платформах округление идёт в другую сторону?

Ещё там часто при преобразовании float к int пишут (int)floor(x) вместо (int)x. Эквивалентны ли эти два варианта?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Округление в сторону нуля гарантировано языком.

Из [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast):

> #### Floating - integral conversions
>
> - A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. If the value can not fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined.

Примерный перевод:

> - Значение типов с плавающей запятой может быть сконвертировано в значение любого целочисленного типа. Дробная часть отбрасывается как в функции `trunc`. Если полученное значение не помещается в диапазон значений целевого типа, поведение программы не определено.

Таким образом, `(int)x` эквивалентно не `(int)floor(x)`, а `(int)trunc(x)`. Разницу можно видеть для отрицательных значений аргумента: [`floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) округляет *всегда вниз*, а [`trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) — всегда в сторону нуля (то есть, вверх для отрицательных чисел и вниз для положительных).